# Freezing point of solution

Tags: equilibrium, solutions, phase

It's stated in my textbook that at the freezing point, the vapour pressure of the solid phase equals the vapour pressure of the liquid phase. In a mixture, since the vapour pressure of the solution is lower than the vapour pressure of pure solvent, the temperature has to be lowered in order for the vapour pressures to equalize and hence freezing to take place.

According to what I understand after reading my textbook, when a solution freezes, it's the solvent which converts into solid and leaves behind liquid phase consisting of both the solvent and solute. Thus, how can the pure solid solvent and liquid phase mixture have the same vapour pressure at the same temperature, since the vapour pressure of pure solvent at any temperature is greater than the vapour pressure of mixture?

Comment: The phrase _"vapour pressure of the solution is lower than the vapour pressure of pure solvent"_  has one crucial word missing.

Comment: Can u tell me what is that word..

Comment: It is "**liquid**". Liquid solution and liquid solvent, correspondingly. (Or solid and solid, but that's less important, as solid solutions are relatively rare.) Most importantly, it is definitely **not** about liquid solution vs solid solvent.

Comment: What they mean having same vapour pressure for liquid and solid phase at equilibrium

Comment: How can a solution have vapour pressure equals to solid solvent at same temperature

Comment: Well, just like that. What's strange or unexpected about it?

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to the textbook?

Comment: My textbook is class 12 ncert textbook..

Comment: @user79504 - consider a liquid and a solid, connected only through the vapor phase. If the solid and liquid are in equilibrium, the vapor pressure _must_ be the same. Otherwise the vapor would be the path to move the higher free energy phase to the lower free energy phase (i.e. the vapor would come off the liquid and condense onto the solid if the solid is the stable phase).

Answer (score 2):

The figure shows the relationship between the solid and liquid solvent and a solution.

Instead of freezing at the freezing point of the solvent $T_1$ a solution freezes at $T_2$, where the vapour pressure of the solution equals that of the pure solid solvent.

Using the Clausius-Clapeyron equation we can show that the solution curve will always intersect the solid solvent curve. The vapour pressure of the solution follows the line $\displaystyle \frac{d\ln(p)}{dT}=\frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{RT}$ and the pure *solid* solvent $\displaystyle \frac{d\ln(p_{ss})}{dT}=\frac{\Delta H_{sub}}{RT}$ where $\Delta H_{sub}$ is the molar heat of sublimation. This in turn is given by $\Delta H_{sub}=\Delta H_{vap}+\Delta H_{fus}$ where 'fus' means heat of fusion. Thus $\Delta H_{sub} \gt \Delta H_{vap}$ which in turn means that the slope of the solid solvent curve is always greater than that of the solution $\displaystyle \frac{d\ln(p_{ss})}{dT} \gt \frac{d\ln(p)}{dT}$.  As the freezing point of the pure solvent is higher than that of the solution the vapour pressure curve of the solid solvent and solution must always intersect.

[image: freezingpoint]